# Remove items from sequence by value of property using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, sequence

I have a sequential list of records. The simplified structure is as follows:

```
Underline Text       Order
-1        Header1    1
-1        SubHeader1 2
0         Data1      3
-1        Header2    4 // this needs to be removed
-1        SubHeader2 5 // this needs to be removed
-1        Header3    6
-1        SubHeader3 7
0         Data3      8
0         Data3a     9
```

Now, since there is no data for the "Header2"/"SubHeader2" pair, it needs to be removed. I can do For...Next loops looking at the "Order" column and make assumptions about items in positions +2 from the current one in the sequence. Is there a way to do this with LINQ?

EDIT: It's an arbitrary list of header pairs and at least one or more data lines. Sometimes data lines are missing. The "Header"/"SubHeader" pair for missing data lines needs to be removed.

EDIT 2: Here's my attempt of removing the unwanted header pairs to alleviate the lack of effort criticism via comments and votes:

```
' Sorry for the VB listing. I thought the C# question tag would reach a wider audience
Class SequentialObject
    Public Property Underline As Integer
    Public Property Text As String
    Public Property Order As Integer
End Class

Shared Sub RemoveHeaderPairsWithNoDataLines()
    Dim sequentialObjectsList As New List(Of SequentialObject)
    Dim itemsToRemove As New List(Of SequentialObject)

    sequentialObjectsList.Add(New SequentialObject With {.Underline = -1, .Text = "Header1", .Order = 1})
    sequentialObjectsList.Add(New SequentialObject With {.Underline = -1, .Text = "SubHeader1", .Order = 2})
    sequentialObjectsList.Add(New SequentialObject With {.Underline = 0, .Text = "Data1", .Order = 3})
    sequentialObjectsList.Add(New SequentialObject With {.Underline = -1, .Text = "Header2", .Order = 4})
    sequentialObjectsList.Add(New SequentialObject With {.Underline = -1, .Text = "SubHeader2", .Order = 5})
    sequentialObjectsList.Add(New SequentialObject With {.Underline = -1, .Text = "Header3", .Order = 6})
    sequentialObjectsList.Add(New SequentialObject With {.Underline = -1, .Text = "SubHeader3", .Order = 7})
    sequentialObjectsList.Add(New SequentialObject With {.Underline = 0, .Text = "Data3", .Order = 8})
    sequentialObjectsList.Add(New SequentialObject With {.Underline = 0, .Text = "Data3a", .Order = 9})

    For Each sequentialObject As SequentialObject In sequentialObjectsList
        ' ignoring here the index out of bounds if current header/subheader are last in the list
        Dim isUnderlinedTwoLinesAhead As Boolean = (sequentialObjectsList(sequentialObject.Order + 2).Underline = -1)

        If isUnderlinedTwoLinesAhead Then
            itemsToRemove.Add(sequentialObject)
        End If
    Next

    For Each itemToRemove As SequentialObject In itemsToRemove
        sequentialObjectsList.Remove(itemToRemove)
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: So your rules here aren't entirely clear. So basically if there's an entry with the text *fooN* and where *foo* is some string and *N* is an int, remove it if there is not a *DataN*? Or is it just a function of their position in the list (in which case is it always 2 items then `Data`? and if not then how do you know to remove those two items and not the next two items?

Comment: Also, is `DataN` the only item that might be missing? Or do you need to ensure that all 3 `Text` types exist for any given `N`?

Comment: You mention that you can do this using a `for/next` loop. It would be helpful if you created a working version of that first, then asked if it could be converted to `Linq`. As it is, the question is slightly confusing.

Comment: What do you do with `Data3a` in this example?

Comment: @Rufus L: Fair enough. I'll do that as soon as I can. The lads are pulling me out for a drink in the pub right now.
"Data3a" is simply to illustrate that there can be more than one data line for the headers pair.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
var exludeTextHashSet = new HashSet<string> { "Header2", "SubHeader2 " };
var result = records.Where(record=>!excludeHashSet.Contains(record.Text))
                    .ToList();
```

Essentially you create a lookup for the text of the records you want to remove and then you filter them out from the initial records by validating that each record that would be include in the resulted list wouldn't have a text value that is contained in the `exludeTextHashSet`.

Comment: This is assuming they already know which items they want to remove (in which case this question is pretty trivial).

Comment: @MattBurland I don't think that he is not aware of this, _ since there is no data for the "Header2"/"SubHeader2" pair, it needs to be removed._. Based on the latter I assume that he does know this. Apparently, I might be wrong. So I hope that OP would shed some light.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `Where` to remove the unwanted records, and then a `Select` to recalculate the correct order from scratch.

How do you determine that there is "no data" for those records?

Comment: I think the trick he's looking for is *how to detect unwanted items*

Comment: With Where you don't remove unwanted records, you select the records you *do* want. The end result is the same, you just need to think differently about the condition.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand the question, but it seems like you are trying to use LINQ on an ordered list in a way that depends on the order of the list. LINQ is not good for this, since it is for IEnumerables which are unordered. I recommend not using LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest organizing your code to be more object-oriented.

```
public class Record
{
    public int Underline { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
}

public class RecordGroup
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Record Header { get; set; }
    public Record SubHeader { get; set; }
    public List<Record> DataList { get; set; }
}
```

---

This way, retrieving `RecordGroup`s containing data would be trivial:

```
List<RecordGroup> recordGroups = ...

recordGroups.Where(g => g.DataList.Any()).OrderBy(g => g.Id);
```